ImageMapster Mouseclick Event
I'm slowly getting into adapting Imagemapster to work the way I want it to.  I'm looking for a way of clicking an area and opening another page with details of that area.  Is there a way of doing this?

I've found the answer, don't bother using ImageMapster, you just need to a use href link to , include the relevant link but still working on how to include target="_blank" which  seems to ignore.

What i did to redirect was I get the embedded id from my  then call an ajax then redirect to corresponding link.I use onClick function of imagemapster
